# Force page reload on history.back on Chrome 31

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

Simplified: I have a very simple index page that lists orders. I pull all orders with something like `select * from orders where deleted_at is null`. Then, each order has a "delete" button that will fire an AJAX routine and remove the row on success without reloading the page. So far, so good.

Now when I delete a few orders using the above described button, navigate away and then go back in the browser's history, the original HTML (including the deleted orders) is rendered and I have to reload the page to see them go away. Any ideas?

This happens in Chrome 31.0.1650.57

Answer (score 0):

Set the *page's* `Cache-Control` header to [`no-store`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.2).

This instructs the browser that it should not store the server's response in cache and that it should make a new request every time it loads the URL.

Comment: It's a nice approach but it's not working unfortunately. Ideally, I would like the browser to keep the JS modified HTML rather to make a new request. This is what Firefox and Safari do.

Comment: [Chrome does not have a back/forward page cache](http://crbug.com/2879), and thus cannot display a page that was modified by script when you click back.

Comment: @Mauro: Also, why doesn't it work?  Setting `Cache-Control: no-store` causes Chrome to issue a new GET request after clicking the back button for me.

Comment: It doesn't happen on my side!

Comment: You're sure you're setting the header on the index page?

Comment: Yes. I tried both PHP's `header()` function and with a meta tag.